# Facebook pagination with graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm kinda new using graph API.I made on my localhost server to import just videos from one facebook page to an website on localhost.

I made a limit for 9 videos on one page but I couldn't get the part with pagination with buttons next and previous.

I watched the documentation and it is pretty complicated "I don't understand it".One time I made "next" button but it shows me pure json not video embeded like on the first page.

```
    require_once 'vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '2062191324084844',
    'app_secret' => 'app-secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',

]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/400880516961734/videos?limit=9',
    'acces-token'
  );

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
/* handle the result */
        ?><div class="row">
        <?php
        foreach ($graphEdge as $graphNode) {
            $id = $graphNode->getField('id');
            echo '
                <div class="col-md-4 mt-2 mb-2">
                <div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/'.$id.'/" data-width="500" data-height="300" data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
                </div>
                ';
        } ?>
        </div>
<?php

    $graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();

// Get the next page of results
$nextPageOfVideos = $fb->next($graphEdge);
// Or the previous page of results
$previousPageOfVideos = $fb->previous($graphEdge);

echo $nextPageOfVideos;
```

Comment: _“but it shows me pure json not video embeded like on the first page”_ - wellyeahduh, that’s because you are not doing with this data, what you did with the original batch – that one you looped over in a foreach, and created very specific HTML code, whereas now with that data for the next page, you just go `echo $nextPageOfVideos;` … You are not really telling us that you are surprised that this gives different results?

Comment: Yeah I wrote above that I made an button to show me that json with echo like this.My question is how to make it to open new page and show me next 9 videos.Any advice?I watched google and documentation but I don't get it.

Comment: Go find yourself a tutorial how pagination is generally implemented in PHP, and modify the part that selects the data accordingly. (In this particular case, that’s your API request. You don’t want to do anything with `$fb->next` in the same page here, but rather you want to specify offset and limit when you make the next API request on the next page.)

Comment: Thanks for advice.Do you got any good tutorial if not I will find something :) I'm pretty green in this part.